# Next.js site returning 304 on initial request

Tags: node.js, next.js

I've got a test server running a production version of my Next.js site on my local network. This is a newly created site with no real complexities, it's linked to a Strapi CMS running on the same machine. The server is built and started using `npm run build` and `npm run start`. I've upgraded to the latest version of Node (20.2.5) and Next.js (14.0.1).

When I first run the site everything is fine, then after a variable amount of time, usually several hours, the site starts returning 304 Not Modified responses.

The problem only occurs on pages that are linked to Strapi, on static pages with no CMS connection the problem doesn't occur and the page loads correctly.

If I stop the server and re-run `npm run start` the problem still occurs. If I run `npm run build` followed by `npm run start`, the problem is resolved.

It's a GET request returning a 304

[image: 304 Response]

The request does not include an `If-None-Match`, `If-Modified-Since`  or an `ETag` header but does include a `Cache-Control: no-cache` header.

[image: Request headers]

The response headers are as follows. A second request within 60 seconds will come back with a `X-Nextjs-Cache: HIT`.

[image: Response headers]

Hosting the site on Vercel it works fine, this is only an issue on my local server.

If anyone can tell me the reason for the 304 errors that would be appreciated. I don't want a workaround that involves never using the cache as correctly performing caching is there for a reason.

Comment: Did you ever find the reason for this or a solution? I'm experiencing similar issues with 304 on content marked as stale even for unconditional requests.